# Attempting COM, Does C# use stdcall by default, or do you have to specify

Tags: c#, c++, com

The book I'm using describes C++ usage of COM and recommends __stdcall as a specifier, arguing that more languages use this method of stack cleanup.

However, I'm considering future interoperability with C#. Does C# use stdcall by default, or does it have to be specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With COM interop, it doesn't matter as much.

If you're using Platform Invocation Services (P/Invoke), with C#, then stdcall is the default.  (Technically, it's [Winapi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx), which defaults to Stdcall on the desktop), but it can be overriden in a `DllImport` specification.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using stdcall as the default specifier as it's the default used by C#. However, it's trivial to change the calling convention via "CallingConvention" attribute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx